# kernel and cokernel of multiplication with 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group and let $f_n \colon A \to A, x \mapsto 2^n x$ be a morphism. Suppose the kernel and cokernel of $f_1$ are finite $2$-groups. I want to show that then the kernel and cokernel of $f_n$ is a finite 2-group, for every $n$.

My idea so far is as follows (with induction):

Suppose this holds for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $g := f_{n-1} |_{\mathrm{ker(f_n)}}$. Then $g$ maps into $\ker(f_1)$, since for $x \in \mathrm{ker(f_n)}$ we have $2g(x) = 2^n x = 0$.
In particular, by assumption the image of $g$ is a finite 2-group.
Further $\ker(g)  = \ker(f_{n-1}) \cap \ker(f_n)$ which is a finite 2-group as well, by induction assumption. By the isomorphism theorem we get further \begin{align*}
\left| \ker(f_n) / \ker(g) \right| = | \mathrm{im}(g) | \end{align*}  and by the Theorem of Lagrange follows that $\ker(f_n)$ is a finite 2-group.

Is this so far right, and how could I prove it for the cokernel? So far I have no idea.

Comment: For kernel, you have considered the exact sequence $$\operatorname{ker}f_{n-1}\hookrightarrow\operatorname{ker}f_n\overset{\times 2^{n-1}}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{ker}f_1 .$$ What can you say about $$\operatorname{coker}f_1\overset{\times 2^{n-1}}{\longrightarrow}\operatorname{coker}f_n\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{coker}f_{n-1}$$?

Comment: I guess this leads to an exact sequence \begin{align*} 0 \to \mathrm{coker} f_1 \to \mathrm{coker} f_n \to \mathrm{coker} f_{n-1} \to 0 \end{align*} which implies that $\mathrm{coker} f_{n-1} \cong \mathrm{coker}f_n/\mathrm{coker} f_1$?

Comment: You are right except that $0\to \operatorname{coker}f_1 \longrightarrow \operatorname{coker}f_n$ might not be exact. However, even if this is the case, the image of $\operatorname{coker}f_1 \longrightarrow \operatorname{coker}f_n$ is still a finite 2-group. By Lagrange, we can conclude that $\operatorname{coker}f_n$ is also a finite 2-group.